# ZSH auto completing with `gitfast` is not disabling internal `git` completion

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I enabled [gitfast](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/gitfast) plugin with antidote and it seems to be enabled. but if
I do not move the

```
mv /usr/share/zsh/5.9/functions/Completion/Unix/_git /usr/share/zsh/5.9/functions/Completion/Unix/_bugit
```

out of the way, the `git checkout feature/<TAB>` still is slow.

How can I disable these internal (?) completions in ZSH? and only use `gitfast`...

My plugin array in `.zplugin` for `antidote` is

```
# Plugins for Antidote
romkatv/zsh-defer

# OMZ Plugins.
ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh path:plugins/vi-mode
ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh path:plugins/gitfast
ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh path:plugins/gcloud
ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh path:plugins/colored-man-pages
ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh path:plugins/command-not-found

z-shell/zsh-navigation-tools

# Prompt Plugin.
romkatv/powerlevel10k

# Completion Plugins.
zsh-users/zsh-completions
sorin-ionescu/prezto path:modules/completion

# These popular core plugins should be loaded at the end
zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions kind:defer
zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting kind:defer
# zdharma-continuum/fast-syntax-highlighting kind:defer
zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search kind:defer
```

Comment: Show your definition of the `plugins` array.

Comment: See above, this is for antidote.